# Convert list result to datatable using linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq, webforms

Convert list result to datatable using linq?

I am getting below error but candidate ID is there in my datatable result.

```
A field or property with the name 'Candidate ID' was not found on the selected data source.
```

Below is my code. I am trying to bind result datat to gridview but error is coming.

```
    var m_strFilePath = "webserviceurl";

    string xmlStr;
    using (var wc = new WebClient())//using Web client downloading xml string  from WEB API
    {
        xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(m_strFilePath);
    }
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = ConvertXMLToDataSet(xmlStr);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables["FL"];



 List<DataTable> result = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("row_Id") == 0)
     .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("row_Id"))
     .Select(grp => grp.CopyToDataTable())
     .ToList();
       GridView1.DataSource = result;
       GridView1.DataBind();
```

Below is gridview design code.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" Width="100%" >
     <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Candidate ID" HeaderText="Id" />

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_viewdetails" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtn_viewdetails_Click" CssClass="btn bg-light-blue-active">View Details</asp:LinkButton>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
     <EmptyDataTemplate>
         <span style="color: red; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; text-align: center; padding-left: 355px;">No records for the entered search details </span>
     </EmptyDataTemplate>
 </asp:GridView>
```

below is result datatable data.

[image]

Comment: Where are you actually filtering/using "Candidate ID" in any form on that LinQ? You have 3 columns: `val`, `FL_Text` and `row_Id`. Looks like that "Candidate ID" you would be looking for is inside `val`, not "Candidate ID" itself as a column/property. That's why it's complaining.

Comment: Can there be a space in the field name specified in the Data Field of Bound Field?? I doubt.

Comment: I have bind val also but getting error.@Gonzo345

Comment: Already I have shown result data-table in the form of image, every think is fine. @GaganDeep

Comment: A field or property with the name 'val' was not found on the selected data source. after adding val as columns, also getting error. @Gonzo345

Comment: Why are you having List<DataTable> ?

Comment: I have updated my question check and i am getting data from web service. @Lucifer

Comment: You can bind a List to a GridView without converting it to a DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

I think your linq query will return a list of `DataRow` not `DataTable`.
So I think it should be `List<DataRow> result = ...`

Then:

```
DataTable newDt = new DataTable();

For(i = 0; i < result.count; i++)
    newDT.add(result[i]);
```

Then set the `DataGridView`

Comment: I'm using a poor smartphone now,  but when I get to a computer I'll complete it.